# Angular ng-options doesn show all elements

Tags: html, angularjs, json, selected, ng-options

I am working in some app with AngularJS and I am using the `ng-options` directive, but I have one problem. When I select the **"Provincia"**, the **"Cantón"** select only shows the last element in the array.

Anyone knows what is the problem?

This is my HTML code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="selected.provincia" ng-options="p.provincia for p in geografiaCR">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Seleccione una provincia</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="selected.nombre" ng-options="n.nombre for n in selected.provincia.cantones">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Seleccione un cantón</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And this is the Angular code:

```js
$scope.selected = {};
$scope.geografiaCR = [
  {
    provincia: 'San José',
    cantones: [{nombre: 'San José',nombre: 'Escazú',nombre: 'Desamparados',nombre: 'Puriscal',nombre: 'Tarrazú',
                nombre: 'Aserrí',nombre: 'Mora',nombre: 'Goicochea',nombre: 'Santa Ana', nombre: 'Alajuelita',
                nombre: 'Acosta',nombre: 'Tibás',nombre: 'Moravia',nombre: 'Montes de Oca',nombre: 'Turrubares',
                nombre: 'Dota',nombre: 'Curridabat',nombre: 'Perez Zeledón', nombre: 'León Cortes'}]
  },
  {
    provincia: 'Limón',
    cantones: [{nombre: 'Limón',nombre: 'Pocosí',nombre: 'Siquirres',nombre: 'Talamanca',nombre: 'Matina',
                nombre: 'Guácimo'}]
  }
];
```

Comment: What is the use of having same name for property?

 Rather it should be

{
    provincia: 'San José',
    cantones: [{nombre: 'San José'},{nombre: 'Escazú'} , {nombre: 'Desamparados'}]
  }

Answer (score 5):

Your `cantones` is one `Object` whose `nombre` property gets overriden repeatedly.

Change

```
cantones: [{nombre: 'Limón',nombre: 'Pocosí',nombre: 'Siquirres',
            nombre: 'Talamanca',nombre: 'Matina', nombre: 'Guácimo'}]
```

To

```
cantones: [{nombre: 'Limón'},{nombre: 'Pocosí'},{nombre: 'Siquirres'},
           {nombre: 'Talamanca'},{nombre: 'Matina'}, {nombre: 'Guácimo'}]
```

Same goes for the other one of course..

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer so it will help to other people.